# YA series about children with powers from their alien parents

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

It's from the 90s, and it's one of those writers like John Peel, or Christopher Pike, or someone like that. I keep thinking it was called something similar to Outer Limits, but that doesn't work.

I can't remember a ton of specifics, but there were a bunch of characters, and they all developed different powers. One kid became a supreme warrior, one was suddenly telepathic, and the one I remember best is a kid who got the short straw - suddenly he found he could speak all known languages (and a bunch more that weren't human.) He said something like, “You guys are all awesome and I'm over here being Translator Boy”.

I think their powers were because their parents were aliens?

I was reading these in the 90s, same time period as Animorphs, Diadem, Fear Street, etc.

Comment: So he was Douglas Ramsey? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/can-anyone-help-me-identify-a-story-about-kids-with-silver-blood; see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91717/novel-about-a-teenage-boy-who-could-understand-all-languages

Answer (score 3):

Might be the Mindwarp series by Chris Archer, the kids all inherit abilities from their parents and have silver blood and stuff. Ethan becomes a super warrior, Toni can control lightning/electricity, another can see the future, sort of.

Comment: And one could speak languages, so that fits.