# Novel about a teenage boy who could understand all languages

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching for the name of a book I've read over 10 years ago (so the book itself should be 10-15 years old) at my school library (in France but I believe it was translated from an American book).

The main character was a boy who discovered he could speak and understand every form of language in the world, be it simple Spanish in class (he discovered it first by becoming fluent and could answer the teacher with ease, without realizing he did it at first) or speaking to rats/insects or even fax machine.

According to [LogicianWithAHat's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91717/novel-about-a-teenage-boy-who-could-understand-all-language?noredirect=1#comment204847_91717), it was part of a series which then featured a girl with regenerative powers and another boy who could, among other things, see in infrared.

There might be something with aliens being the cause of it and they began to develop their power to fight them, but I'm unsure about that part (I never finished the series at the time). It's been a long time but I liked the idea of this apparently useless power which turned out to be actually very cool.

Comment: "could be moth"?

Comment: @SeanDuggan If I'm not misunderstanding, I recall he could understand the speach of moths (or some kind of bugs) - although they don't really have any speach to speak of - or I'm confusing with Animorph but I believe there was something like that.

Comment: No, that makes sense. :) I just wanted to be certain it wasn't a mispelling for something else.

Comment: I think he also managed to talk to a fax machine? I can't remember the name of the series, but I recall coming across it. Other books featured a girl with regenerative powers and another boy who could (presumably among other things) see in infrared

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat Yes, that's it! :)

Comment: @Ananas I came across it in the UK, so it definitely existed outside of France. Don't know if that helps, since neither of us know the name.  

Other things I remember: he told his spanish teacher that it sounded like she learned spanish in a taco bell, at one point he talked to either rats or insects to get them to free him when tied up, and in the girl's book, she spent a lot of time wondering what would happen if she were cut in half

Comment: It seems to have similarities with "Guardians Inc: The Cypher". http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10764418-the-cypher

Comment: @EngrStudent: I'm reading that one myself and I'm doubtful as the Cypher can only read any language and his discovery is via a newspaper ad, then a cloth calling card from a black magician.

Comment: semi-duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/can-anyone-help-me-identify-a-story-about-kids-with-silver-blood (about series in general)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Alien Scream** by Chris Archer. 1997

Since he turned 13, he can suddenly speak several languages fluently--and he overheard someone talking about killing him in a language not even human.

[http://www.amazon.com/Alien-Scream-Mind-Warp-3/dp/0671014846](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671014846) (see reviews)

Google Books has snippet views of some of the text, such as the Taco Bell conversation with the teacher.

Comment: That's it, the **MindWarp** series, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! You're welcome.