# Trying to recall old YA Sci-Fi series similar to Animorphs

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, young-adult

I recall a young adult book series similar to *Animorphs* where kids had special abilities to stop an alien invasion. The main difference is instead of turning into animals, they were more normal but enhanced skills. For example, one kid could speak any language including fax noise. Another kid could use any form of martial arts. I believe I also recall something about silver blood.

Comment: You hint at remembering more details. For example, can you remember any of the other powers? What any characters looked like? Can you remember why the aliens were invading? How many books in the series? etc. If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into your question!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're looking for the [*Mindwarp* series by Chris Archer](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61016-mindwarp). It's come up a few times on the site.

*[Alien Terror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21021.Alien_Terror)*

[image: Front cover of Mindwarp: Alien Terror]

> As the legend goes, an alien landed in the cornfields of Metier, Wisconsin. After a short while most of the aliens left. But others assimilated and cross-bred with humans. These children have lived ordinary lives--until now. At age 13, these offspring will manifest their alien powers . . . and have been targeted for termination. In "Alien Terror", Ethan Rogers used to be a wimp. But suddenly he knows martial arts, wrestling moves, combat skills and even weaponry. He'd think it was pretty cool--if he wasn't running for his life

*[Alien Scream](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1807364.Alien_Scream)*

> Jack Raynes ignored the anonymous note he got on his 13th birthday saying his life was in danger. That was a big mistake. Since he turned 13, he can suddenly speak several languages fluently--and he overheard someone talking about killing him in a language not even human.

The silver blood is indeed a plot point, as mentioned in other questions on this site. The first six books are largely each centered on the story of one of the children, with the next four involving their combined adventures.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105150/23243 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15847/23243 among others.